# $scope.myObjectVariable value set to input attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

Good evening,

I am writing an application using AngularJS and I require for the application to send data with a POST request to the nodejs server.

My data is structured like as a json object and it has data binding thanks to the AngularJS framework.

As of now, a function is dynamically trying to create possible values that the user might like inside of some `input` tags. An example:

```
<button ng-click="generateFoodAndBeverages(row)>Generate</button>
<input type="text" ng-model="row.service.day.beverage" placeholder="beverage" />
<input type="text" ng-model="row.service.day.food" placeholder="food" />
```

The two input values can be set by the user by typing in the value they would like (*e.g. "Cola", "Hamburger"*), but above the input tags is a button that can generate the input values for the user.

The function that generates the values takes them from an array and then at the end of the function returns two possible values, one for beverages and one for food.

When it has the two returning values it changes the attribute value of both inputs, setting them to the two possibilities generated by the function:

```
jQuery("#input1").attr("value", generateFoodAndBeverages(row)[0]);
jQuery("#input2").attr("value", generateFoodAndBeverages(row)[1]);
```

This is not perfect nor elegant but it's working. The function populates and dynamically changes the value attribute of those two input elements each time the user requests for automatic generation of food and beverages so the values are actually set and do exist.

Even so, even if I see them on screen as text inside the input fields, my POST request does not recognize the fact that the ng-model actually changed. The only way the ng-model registers the changes to the value attribute of the input fields is if the user types something with his keyboard, manually changing the value attribute. Another example:

```
<input type="text" value="generateValue()" ng-model="row.service.info" />
```

The one up here does not change the ng-model value at all.

```
<input type="text" value="User Typed Value" ng-model="row.service.info" />
```

This other one instead does change the ng-model value and as it changes and exists, it is passed to the $scope that can later be sent as a POST request to the server.

Any ideas as to why the "automatically and dynamically generated" value of the input field does not get registered by the ng-model while the user typed value does?

Thanks in advance!

> [EDIT]

Apparently the problem comes with the `ng-model` not changing. I tried to debug the problem by applying an `ng-change` in the input. If the change is done by javascript, it is not registered with the `ng-model` and the `ng-change` function does not fire because the `ng-model` was not changed even tho' I can clearly see the new value set by javascript for the input tag. If I change the value of the input tag by hand the `ng-change` is fired and the console logs the change.

I could apply the changes directly to the `ng-model` if it weren't so different for each row.

Having the ng-model like this:

```
<input ng-model="row.serviceInfo.DayObject[dayString].food" />
<input ng-model="row.serviceInfo.DayObject[dayString].beverage" />
```

How would I be able to apply the changes directly to the ng-model given how dynamic the model is. As an example, I could have 1000 rows, each with their own serviceInfo object. I don't know how I could change the model for each of those rows with the dynamically generated values.

> [EDIT]

The problem was indeed with ng-model not changing. The solution consisted in applying the changes to the ng-model for each element inside the dynamically generated values function. Thanks everyone for the input. I'll leave this piece of code here if anyone ever comes across the same problem! Thanks again!

```
      let foodEl = angular.element(the row element food input);
      let beverageEl = angular.element(the row element beverage input);

      $scope.displayedCollection[i].serviceInfo = {
        "day" : {
          "food" : generatedValuesFood(el, day),
          "beverage" : generatedValuesBeverage(el, day)
        }
      };

      foodEl.val($scope.displayedCollection[i].serviceInfo.day.food);
      beverageEl.val($scope.displayedCollection[i].serviceInfo.day.beverage);
```

Comment: Hi, try to simplify the thing here

Comment: Your code seems a bit complex so it's difficult to be sure (maybe you could create a plunker with the bare minimum?) but the explanation seems to be because you're doing the change with jQuery. My theory is that you're using ".attr", maybe you should use ".prop" to actually change the value of the property, but even then, I'm not sure it would work. Anyway, I wouldn't mix Angular and jQuery for this specific purpose, you should try to use Angular binding everywhere.

Comment: You are right, I am using .attr on the jQuery part to change the value of the input elements and the value is not registered inside the ng-model binding when generated by the function.

Comment: You mean that it works with `.prop`?

Comment: Nop, it does not. It does not work with .prop("value", "my value"), or .val("my value") or .attr("value", "my value")

I am using jQuery to change this but I guess it wouldnt matter even if I used native javascript, dunno. Ill let you know tho'

Comment: Apparently the problem comes with the ng-model not changing. I tried to debug the problem by applying an ng-change in the input. If the change is done by javascript, it is not registered with the ng-model and the ng-change function does not fire because the ng-model was not changed even tho' I can clearly see the new value set by javascript for the input tag. If I change the value of the input tag by hand the ng-change is fired and the console logs the change.

I could apply the changes directly to the ng-model if it weren't so different for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is quite simple. As @ssougnez said, don't mixed jquery with angularjs. Angularjs use data-binding concept, don't use jquery style to change the input value instead use the ng-model directive to bind data from the model to the view on HTML controls (input, select, textarea). In your generateFoodAndBeverages function just set the ng-model value according to which row for eg:

```
var generateFoodAndBeverages = function () {
     $scope.row.service.day.beverage = array[0];
     $scope.row.service.day.food = array[1];
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me to solve the problem in its own way :D